# How to change range as loop changes - Run time error '1004': Application-define or object-define error

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to go through worksheet(PasteHere) and match the name with worksheet(Breakdown). When the two name matches, I need to copy the range from worksheet(PasteHere) and paste into worksheet(Breakdown). For some reason I am getting a run time error that does not allow me to use the current range to copy and paste.

```
Sub Stats()

Dim Row As Integer
Dim RowP As Integer
Dim Col As Integer

For Row = 2 To 200
    For RowP = 2 To 200
        If Worksheets("PasteHere").Cells(RowP, 2) = Worksheets("Breakdown").Cells(Row, 2) Then 
            Worksheets("PasteHere").Range("IRowP:CRRowP").Copy Worksheets("Breakdown").Range("IRow:CRRow")
        End If    
    Next RowP
Next Row

MsgBox "Done"

End Sub
```

Comment: `Range("I" & RowP & ":CR" & RowP)`, and `Range("I" & Row & ":CR" & Row)`. I'm sure there's a duplicate question somewhere here on SO :)

Answer (score 0):

```
Dim Row As Integer
Dim RowP As Integer
Dim Col As Integer

For Row = 2 To 200
    For RowP = 2 To 200
        If Worksheets("PasteHere").Cells(RowP, 2) = Worksheets("Breakdown").Cells(Row, 2) Then 
            Worksheets("PasteHere").Range("I" & RowP & ":CR" & RowP).Copy Worksheets("Breakdown").Range("I" & Row & ":CR" & Row)
        End If    
    Next RowP
Next Row

MsgBox "Done"

End Sub
```

When you use the Row and RowP variables you have to jump out of the double quote vba string and use the & character to concat.